# How to check whether Advanced Currency Management is enabled in Apex?

Tags: multi-currency

It looks like that if multi-currency is enabled, DatedConversionRate object is created even if ACM is not enabled. Is there some other way to check whether ACM is enabled?

Sorry for creating a new question for this but I am unable to comment on the [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53824/how-to-identify-advanced-currency-is-enabled-in-apex-class)

Comment: This provides some details around your ask. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216875/how-to-identify-advanced-currency-management-acm-is-enabled

Answer (score 0):

If DatedConversionRate object is created without ACM being enable, I assume it wouldn't contain any records per se. So you might want to query on it and then check if it contains any records.