# How to identify Advanced Currency Management (ACM) is enabled

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, tooling-api, multi-currency

Is there a way to find if the  `Advanced Currency Management`enabled using api or apex or soql?

I have able to check if the multi-currency is enabled by using the api endpoint `/services/data/v40.0/connect/organization` but could not able to find how to find if ACM is enabled, is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From research:

If Multiple Currencies is not enabled:

- The `CurrencyType` and `DatedConversionRate` Sobjects are not exposed.

If Multiple Currencies is enabled:

- Both `CurrencyType` and `DatedConversionRate` Sobjects are exposed.
- But, if Advanced Currency Management (ACM) is not enabled, `DatedConversionRate` is not createable (by checking the Sobject's describe).
- When ACM is enabled

  - `DatedConversionRate` is createable.
  - `DatedConversionRate` will have at least one record.
- ACM can be disabled, and when disabled:

  - `DatedConversionRate` will no longer be createable.
  - `DatedConversionRate` records will still persist.

Comment: To be more precise here, just to check whether sobject is createable or not does not help. You need to check creatable attribute for `DatedConversionRate.IsoCode` field.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check if the metadata is present for [DatedConversionRate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm). It should only show up if

> multicurrency and the effective dated currency features are enabled.

Currently you will need to drop out to either the REST API or the SOAP API to do this. See [Updating multi currency rates from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/13282/102)

Comment: what will be the rest api endpoint?

Comment: Yes. A REST API endpoint like `/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/DatedConversionRate/`. Start with `/services/data/v42.0/sobjects` and see if it comes back as a defined sObject against that org.

Comment: did not work, i have NOT enabled  ACM and I still see the `sobject/DatedConversionRate` in the api endpoint.

Comment: While hitting : /services/data/v54.0/sobjects/DatedConversionRate/describe
you need to check  "createable": false, that means ACM is disabled 
if it is true that means ACM is enabled since you have option to turn on/off ACM anytime. Hope this helps.